# Im new to Scala and want to know how this function work

Tags: scala

Im trying to implement an algorithm called **Connection Scan Algorithm** in C or JavaScript or Java programming language and found this Scala implementation:
https://github.com/dbsystel/practical-csa that I wan my implementation to be based on

Fisrt here are the types

```
class Stop(id: Int, name: String)
class StopTime(tripId: Int, arrivalTime: Long, departureTime: Long, stopId: Int, stopSequence: Int)
class Trip(routeId: Int, serviceId: Int, id: Int, tripHeadsign: String)
```

Im trying to understand what this function is doing 
https://github.com/dbsystel/practical-csa/blob/master/src/main/scala/gtfs/GTFSData.scala#L28

```
private def sinceEpoch(date: LocalDateTime, time: Long): Long = {
    epoch.until(date, ChronoUnit.MINUTES) + time
}

private def makeConnectionsFromStops(trip: Trip, date: LocalDateTime)(timedStops: List[StopTime]): List[TripConnection] = timedStops match {
  case from :: to :: rest =>
    TripConnection(
      from.stopId,
      to.stopId,
      sinceEpoch(date, from.departureTime),
      sinceEpoch(date, to.arrivalTime), trip.id
    ) :: makeConnectionsFromStops(trip, date)(to :: rest)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

It get called from:
https://github.com/dbsystel/practical-csa/blob/master/src/main/scala/gtfs/GTFSData.scala#L74

```
// Lets assume thats this is full of objects
val associatedTrips: List[Trip] = List[Trip]()

val timestamp = LocalDateTime()

associatedTrips flatMap {
  trip => stopTimes.get(trip.id) map makeConnectionsFromStops(trip, timestamp) getOrElse Nil
}
```

### What I want to know is:

1. What is **from**, **to** and **rest** from the first block of code, I think  **from** is the first element in the array, **to** is the second element of the  array and **rest** is the rest of the elements without from or to. Is this  correct?
2. What does **to :: rest** contain (when calling makeConnectionsFromStops recursively), what is it doing?
3. What the last line of code is doing?

can some make a pseudo implementation in Java or JavaScript so I would understand because i'm new to Scala.

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Please **don't** spam unrelated tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions, I'm not a native speaker, so I hope everything will be clear :

1. Yes, `from` is the first element, `to` is the second and `rest` is the tail of the List.
2. `to :: rest` should be a List with `to` as the head, and `rest` as the tail
3. To understand the last line (I think you're speaking about `case _ => Nil`), you have to understand how pattern matching work. Roughly speaking, if `timedStops` is a List with at least 2 elements (`from` and `to`), the `TripConnection` part is called. Otherwise, the function return the Nil element (an empty List) ending the recursion.

I don't know if we can give advices about courses here (if we can't, please moderate me), but I would advise you to take the "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" course on coursera. That's one of the best if you want to take a good start in Scala (and it's free).

Comment: Hello, I found another function here: https://github.com/dbsystel/practical-csa/blob/master/src/main/scala/algorithm/Csa.scala#L12. What does **[C <: Connection]** mean? is it a template type.

Comment: C is a type parameter. <: Connection is a bound, meaning that the type C passed as a parameter must be a subclass of Connection.